# How to do animations on flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation, mobile-application

I am making an application on Flutter. there are 2 big containers on my screen. these containers are clickable and they allow me to go to other pages. When I click, I want the containers to go left to left in order and I want the new page to come to the screen from right to left. But I have no idea how to do this. I don't have much idea about animations, I only know how to use animations on getx. I wonder where I can learn how to create my own animations.

my codes on my main screen:

```
class ReqHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReqHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundcolor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children:[
            CustomPaint(painter: BackgroundPainter(),child: SizedBox(width: Get.width, height: Get.height,),),
            Column(
            children: [
              Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                height: Get.height *0.08,
                width: Get.width *0.5, 
                child:  const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 25),
                  child: Text('Name Surname'),
                ),),
                SizedBox(
                  height: Get.height *0.08,
                  width: Get.width *0.5, 
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon:  const Icon(Icons.language),),
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: const  Icon(Icons.logout),)
                  ]),),
                ],),
              const Divider(thickness: 2,),
              const SizedBox(height: 50,),
              BigButtons(backgroundImage: 'assets/form.jpg' ,ontap: (){Get.to(const ReqFormCreate(),);}, text: 'BlaBla'),
              const SizedBox(height: 50,),
              BigButtons(backgroundImage: 'assets/documents2.jpg', text: 'BlaBlaBla', ontap: (){}),
              const SizedBox(height: 50,),
              const egeTechnoTextButton()
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have searched in many places but I am even more confused

Comment: check [Introduction to animations](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations) and [Animations tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

this is custom fade animation widget

```
class FadeInAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const FadeInAnimation({super.key, required this.child, required this.delay});

  final Widget child;
  final double delay;

  @override
  State<FadeInAnimation> createState() => _FadeInAnimationState();
}

class _FadeInAnimationState extends State<FadeInAnimation>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation<double> animation;
  late Animation<double> animation2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * widget.delay).round()),
        vsync: this);
    animation2 = Tween<double>(begin: -40, end: 0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // The state that has changed here is the animation object’s value.
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.forward();
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(0, animation2.value),
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: animation.value,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

You can use any container or any widget .when page build or open time this animation works

```
                    FadeInAnimation(
 delay: 2, child: child: Center(
                          child: Container(width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                          color: Colors.amber,),
                        )
)
```